# Show icon on item hover

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to show an edit icon on a cells hover state, using font awesome.

How can make the class name unique so I can target it with css for each row?

```
import {Icon} from 'react-fa'

if(this.props.day.achievements) {
   listItems = this.props.day.achievements.map((achievement) => (
       <div className="cell" key={achievement + "_achievements"}>
         {achievement}
        <div className="edit">
          <a href="#">
            <Icon name="pencil-square" className="edit" />
          </a>
        </div>
       </div>
   ))
}
```

I am using the following css:

```
.cell:hover .edit {
    display: block;
}

.edit {
    padding-top: 7px;   
    padding-right: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.edit a {
    color: #000;
}
```

How can I display the icon for each cell?

Comment: where's the icon's code... what kind of icon? `font` or `svg` or what?

Comment: fontAwesome I have just updated question

Comment: You shouldn't need the class `edit` on both the wrapper and the icon. Just the wrapper. You can also style the anchor `<a>` as display:block to save yourself the extra div. Also what is your question? Is the code you provided not working?

Comment: Its only showing for one row, do I need to create a unique class name dynamically?

Comment: Since you're using position:absolute on the edit wrapper, try adding position:relative to the .cell. I suspect your icons ARE showing but they're all floating up to the top overlapping with each other.

Comment: Ah yes of course, brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: PS: I uprated your Q. I don't like it when people downrate unclear Q's without first giving the OP a chance to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using position:absolute on the edit wrapper, try adding position:relative to the .cell. I suspect your icons ARE showing but they're all floating up to the top overlapping with each other.